# Gmail does not send file shared through intent, but gives "invalid attachments" error

Tags: android, gmail, attachment, android-fileprovider

I am trying to share a file stored in getExternalFilesDir() through ACTION_SEND intent. I use a FileProvider to grant permission and create the uri. The chooser that pops up includes Signal, Gmail, and Drive. If I choose Drive, the action succeeds and the file is uploaded properly to my account. If I choose signal, it succeeds and my friend gets the file. If I choose Gmail, the action appears to succeed and I see a message with an attachment with the right name and size. I fill in the "to" field and hit send, the composer disappears, but no message is sent or saved and there is a logcat error: >java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found invalid attachments while sending the draft.

Here is the Manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Here is provider_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path
        name="data"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

Here is where the intent is built and started in MainActivity:

```
     val uri = getUriForFile(
                    applicationContext,
                    "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileprovider",
                    file
            )

            Log.d(TAG, "send uri: " + uri)


            Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    .apply {
                        //setType("text/plain") // works for drive, but fails for email
                        setType("application/zip")
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Armonitor Record:" + file.nameWithoutExtension)
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "See attached...")
                        setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION.or( FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION))
                    }
                    .also {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(it, "share file with"));
                    }
```

I know the fileprovider authority is working because when I disrupt it I get an error before the chooser is shown. I tried manually granting permissions to any consumer of the intent in case the permissions would only apply to the setData uri. I have tried various file types, including "application/octal", "text/plain", "message/rfc822". The files I am trying to send are between 0.2 and 38 kB and I have tried .txt and .zip files. I did notice that if I change the "from" address to a different gmail account, the attachment disappears completely. The email can be sent successfully without the attachment. I don't have another email client configured on my phone.

Here is the logcat messages from gmail for an attempt to send a small <1kB zip file with type="application/zip". A larger zipfile (4kB) had a slightly different result -- compose event failed with exception 1, but no invalid attachments error, and the email was saved and sent without the attachment:

```
2019-07-05 11:29:22.944 11320-13752 W/Gmail: ComposeActivity:Failed to retrieve reference message with uri=null.
2019-07-05 11:29:22.980 2013-2107 I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed com.google.android.gm/.ComposeActivityGmailExternal,wp,ca,316
2019-07-05 11:29:22.981 2013-2107 I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.google.android.gm/.ComposeActivityGmailExternal: +312ms
2019-07-05 11:29:22.988 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No collectionId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:22.988 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No itemId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:23.011 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No collectionId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:23.011 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No itemId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:23.016 11320-11320 W/Gmail: ComposeActivity:b/119949571:In finishSetup.
2019-07-05 11:29:23.019 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:b/119949571:loading bodyWebView with template emit size of 1898.
2019-07-05 11:29:23.114 11320-11320 E/Gmail: Gmail:EditWebView JS Console: b/119949571:draft.editor.onLoad; source: file:///android_asset/draft_editor_gmail_compiled.js at 87
2019-07-05 11:29:23.121 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No collectionId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:23.121 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No itemId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:23.124 11320-11320 E/Gmail: Gmail:EditWebView JS Console: b/119949571:draft.editor.onLoad is finished; source: file:///android_asset/draft_editor_gmail_compiled.js at 88
2019-07-05 11:29:23.149 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No collectionId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:23.149 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No itemId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:26.175 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No collectionId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:26.175 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No itemId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:37.855 11320-13837 W/Gmail: Gmail:No collectionId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:37.856 11320-13837 W/Gmail: Gmail:No itemId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:37.858 11320-13837 W/Gmail: Gmail:No collectionId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:37.858 11320-13837 W/Gmail: Gmail:No itemId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:37.893 11320-11320 E/Gmail: Gmail:Compose Event 1 failed with reason=1
2019-07-05 11:29:37.909 11320-13837 E/Gmail: sapishim:Exception in saveOrSendDraft: method=send_message
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found invalid attachments while sending the draft
        at afiw.a(SourceFile:3)
        at afiw.get(SourceFile:7)
        at gch.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.gm.sapi.SapiUiProvider.call(SourceFile:32)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:403)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:1756)
        at din.a(SourceFile:109)
        at din.a(SourceFile:602)
        at doa.run(SourceFile:11)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at ghw.dispatchMessage(SourceFile:1)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found invalid attachments while sending the draft
        at jbx.a(Unknown Source:4)
        at afjm.a(SourceFile:2)
        at afjj.run(SourceFile:6)
        at aflq.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at addr.run(SourceFile:2)
        at abql.run(Unknown Source:3)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
2019-07-05 11:29:37.910 11320-13837 E/Gmail: Gmail:Draft send failed with reason=11
2019-07-05 11:29:37.943 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No collectionId found for event forward
2019-07-05 11:29:37.943 11320-11320 W/Gmail: Gmail:No itemId found for event forward
```

What does Gmail consider "Invalid attachments"? How can I share these files through Gmail?

I've heard gmail has settings for allowed types and sizes of attachments, but I'm not sure how to find them or whether that is what's happening here.

Thanks for any ideas you may have.

Comment: "I have tried various file types, including "application/octal", "text/plain", "message/rfc822"" -- what is the actual type of file that you are trying to share? Note that `application/octal` is not a recognized MIME type; you may be thinking of `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant. I want to share zip files and text files. I tried all of the types with both types of file, as well as "application/zip"

Comment: If you try sharing through Gmail and get the failure, does Logcat include any messages from Gmail that provide any clues? If other apps can read the content, and if you are accurately describing the content via the MIME type, I do not know why Gmail would have a problem with the content.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is probably too dumb to be helpful, but I did solve this. It was that my provider_paths file only listed

```
<external-files-path
    name="data"
    path="."/>
```

and I was saving the zip files in a subfolder, so I needed to add

```
<external-files-path
    name="zip"
    path="./zip" />
```

I don't know why it worked for sharing through Signal and Drive, but Gmail was pickier. But now it works for them all, so yay!

Answer (score 0):

If you also add it as `ClipData`, the permission grant will work successfully:

```
yourIntent.clipData = ClipData.newUri(context.contentResolver, fileName, contentUri)
```

The reason is that `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` will work only for `Intent.data` and `Intent.clipData`, and not for extras, unless the uri permission grant has been given explicitly (inconvenient), or has been given by also adding a `ClipData`.